# "or" doesn't work as expected, but bitwise or "|" works well

Tags: python, logic, depth-first-search

I wrote a simple **DFS** program as follows.

I think **Line 20 (Bitwise OR)** and **Line 21 (OR)** are interchangeable. But in fact, if I change Line 20 into Line 21, the program will fail to find all the paths.

```
line 20: flag = (flag | self.dfs(i, target))
lin 21: flag = (flag or self.dfs(i, target))
```

It may have something to do with the recursion probably. I really wonder why. Could anyone help answer my confusion?

```
class FindTarget:
    def __init__(self, map):
        self.map = map
        self.temp_path = []
        self.ans_path = []
        self.visited = set()

    def dfs(self, node, target):
        #stop condition
        if node == target:
            self.ans_path.append(self.temp_path + [node])
            return True

        #recursion
        flag = False
        self.temp_path.append(node)
        self.visited.add(node)
        for i in map[node]:
            if i not in self.visited:
                flag = (flag | self.dfs(i, target))
                # flag = (flag or self.dfs(i, target))

        #backtrack
        self.temp_path.pop()
        if flag: self.visited.remove(node)
        return flag


    def solve(self, node, target):
        return self.dfs(node, target)


map = {1:[2,3],2:[3,9],3:[2,9],9:[1,2]}
solver = FindTarget(map)
print(solver.solve(1, 9))
print(solver.ans_path)
```

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.

Comment: We also expect that you will trace the suspect  values just before the point of error. Where are you confused about how they got to those values?  If  you suspect that recursion is part of your problem, then where is your trace of the recursive process?

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your advice. I am a new user here. I will follow you advice and learn to write better questions.

Answer (score 2):

Logical `or` uses lazy evaluation which means that it only calculates the second value if needed. Bitwise `|` always calculates the second value.

```
flag = True or bool(print('logical'))
flag = True | bool(print('bitwise'))
```

Comment: Oh! I got it. When the flag is True, my dfs function will not be called. Your answer is perfect. Thanks a lot